# mod_rewrite - 301 re-direct issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been wrestling with this seemingly simple re-direct task for hours now and for the life of me cannot get it going.. Whether I pass in the value of **1** *or* **19** in url, in both cases it re-directs me to **http://mywebsite.com/catalogue-gifts/chicks**. (ideally, I want the second condition/rule to bring user to **http://mywebsite.com/catalogue-gifts/mango-fruit-trees/**)

Below is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pID=1<br />
RewriteRule ^product_details2\.asp$ http://mywebsite.com/catalogue-gifts/chicks$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pID=19<br />
RewriteRule ^product_details2\.asp$ http://mywebsite.com/catalogue-gifts/mango-fruit-trees$1? [L,R=301]
```

Any help is much appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `RewriteCond` match is a regular expression with bounds. Therefore, if you have in the query string:

```
pID=19
```

it will match `pID=1`, because it doesn't check the end of the query string, `pID=1` is part of `pID=19`.

You need to change your conditions to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pID=1(&|$)
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pID=19(&|$)
```

The `(&|$)` at the end means after those numbers, you have either a `&` character (for another parameter) or the end of the string (`$`).

Additionally, if you are worried about other query string parameters that may end with a `pID`, like `foopID`, then you should add a boundary check to the front of those regex, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pID=1(&|$)
```

So the `(^|&)` is either the beginning of the query string, or a `&` character.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much.. I appreciate the time of day and explanation to the solution - Cheers!